# Qt 6.3 QML image resizing not working, why?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

new bee here. I am trying something very simple and it is not working and I cannot figure out why.

I am on windows and according to to the documentation, I can easily re-size an image using "fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit"

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html

Here is the QML code

```
import QtQuick

Image {
    id: buttonId
    width: 60
    height: 100
    source: "large1.png"
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
}
```

This is getting included from a parent QML as such:

```
RowLayout
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: spacerWidth
    
            MyImage {
    }
}
```

The source image is 334x484 px

[image]

but here is what I get when I render the page:

[image]

my window is set to 480x272

```
Window {
    width: 480
    height: 272
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")
```

What such a simple scaling is not working?

thank you.

Comment: If you're using a `Layout`, you must use `Layout.preferredWidth` to define the `width` of the children *since the `Layout` is in responsible of the geometry of the children*, according to the documentation for [Qt Quick Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#a-simple-layout).

Comment: To make it more universal, i.e. to work within Layouts and non-Layouts, try setting implicitWidth and implicitHeight instead. Else you be wondering, is this (1) a width/height situation, or (2) a Layout.preferredWidth/Layout.preferredHeight situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your component:

- into `Layout` - assign to `Layout.preferredWidth` / `Layout.preferredHeight` properties
- **not** in `Layout` - assign to `width` and `height` properties

User Stephen Quan is not right, because if you're will be using `implicit` values for define `Layout.preferred` values - it will be always `sourceSize` width and height values which correspond original image size (if this was received from filesystem) **OR** concrete custom values (e.g. from database, or user-defined value) if you received this pixmap from `QQuickImageProvider`

If you're will be assign values to `implicit` `width/height` `Image` properties - it will be error, because it's a `read-only` properties

Answer (score 0):

With the user "SMR" help, it scaled properly as below:

Image {
id: buttonId
fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
Layout.preferredWidth: 60
Layout.preferredHeight: 100